# VS2010 Find and Replace numeric list

Tags: c#, regex, search, replace

I need help using regular expressions in VS2010. I want to Find:

```
Environment.Exit(0); ... 
Environment.Exit(0);
```

and replace it with:

```
File.WriteAllText("code",1); Environment.Exit(0); ...
File.WriteAllText("code",2); Environment.Exit(0);
```

i just need to know where my program terminating. So i have many Environment.exit in different files.

Comment: A better option would be to refactor your calls to `Environment.Exit(..)`. This would give you a single point of exit from a coding perspective and you can examine the call stack before leaving the application.

Comment: i have more than 50 call of Env.Exit() just technickly i need to replace this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = "Environment.Exit(0);" +
                           "Environment.Exit(0);";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Environment.Exit\(0\);", new MatchEvaluator(MyReplacement));
        }   
        static int count = 1;
        static string MyReplacement(Match match)
        {
            return string.Format("File.WriteAllText(\"code\",{0}); Environment.Exit(0);", count++); 
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: thanks but i still hope standard visual studio searching tool will solve my problem. But as you suggest, the most efficient way to solve this task is to write another program to complete writing of main program.

Comment: The VS editor doesn't have macro functionality to increment the numeric value like some more sophisticated editors.